# OOM killer never runs

Tags: 20.04, ram

For some reason, when my system runs out of free RAM, the system freezes and doesn't ever unfreeze. This often also has the disastrous result of the ext4 driver dying. My question is, how do I make the default OOM killer actually do anything?

I have checked all the other threads about this, but they really haven't helped and most of them are ancient by now. I've tried increasing `admin_reserve_kbytes` and set `oom_kill_allocating_task`, no effect. SysRq doesn't do anything either. By now I suspect that there really isn't a solution for this.

Comment: Why not use swap? Read `man mkswap swapon`.

Comment: @waltinator I have used swap, same end result.